# Character encoding with msysgit

Tags: git, encoding, msysgit

Commit messages created on my winXP box generate warnings when read on my Win7 box.

My name contains special characters (ö), I suppose that this is the source of the problem since my name is in the commit.
I saw the problem while trying to stash changes on a commit created on winXP:
`Warning: commit message does not conform to UTF-8.`

I would like to check what encoding was used to generate the commit on winXP, but can't find how.

`$ git config --get i18n.commitencoding`
returns blank on both machines.

http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-commit.html seems to say that git checks the encoding in the commit objects.

> git log, git show, git blame and
>   friends look at the encoding header of
>   a commit object, and try to re-code
>   the log message into UTF-8 unless
>   otherwise specified.

That is fine, but then why does git complain on win7 and not on winXP?

---

msysgit versions are identical on both machines: 1.7.4.msysgit.0.

Comment: By which soft do you generated the file name with special char "o:"? With `msys` or with navive windows apps?

Answer (score 0):

Just a wild guess but I had a similar problem with letters in someone's name in a Rakefile recently and I actually had to change the encoding of my CMD environment to run it.

Look at step number two on this wiki:

https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/Having-trouble-with-rake%3F

The Microsoft documentation on the chcp command is here:
http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/chcp.mspx?mfr=true

Answer (score 0):

Using [i18n.commitEncoding](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-i18ncommitEncoding) is better supported with modern Git (2019), but only Git 2.25 (Q1 2020), provides a full support: Handling of commit objects that use non UTF-8 encoding during "`rebase -i`" has been improved.

See [commit 52f52e5](https://github.com/git/git/commit/52f52e5ae4937de2bc798828c47c49f469b2cc85), [commit 5772b0c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5772b0c745ea7f57b94880f377e84a79e2675f38) (11 Nov 2019), [commit b375744](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b375744274113889c85bee69445375ce51e96648), [commit 019a9d8](https://github.com/git/git/commit/019a9d836230c8851aa8b0d4dc2e0dea42662a90), [commit 0798d16](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0798d16fe38e45453b626c699d92de6f9d71f5ac), [commit e4b95b3](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e4b95b3b5fb36bfa3db4408dd469a123c6efc51f), [commit 1ba6e7a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1ba6e7aecdd2c72df1b0da7a89502e82485f7819) (08 Nov 2019), and [commit 99b2ba3](https://github.com/git/git/commit/99b2ba35f5a67dd6308b265a8e4c3a92e2e67221) (07 Nov 2019) by [Doan Tran Cong Danh (`congdanhqx-zz`)](https://github.com/congdanhqx-zz).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 6511cb3](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6511cb33c918e5156cfff32f70b33dc65380760e), 01 Dec 2019)</sup>

> ### [`sequencer`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5772b0c745ea7f57b94880f377e84a79e2675f38): reencode old merge-commit message
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Doan Tran Cong Danh</sup>
>
> During rebasing, old merge's message (encoded in old encoding) will be used as message for new merge commit (created by rebase).
>
> In case of the value of `i18n.commitencoding` has been changed after the old merge time. We will receive an unusable message for this new merge.
>
> Correct it.

---

> ### [`sequencer`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0798d16fe38e45453b626c699d92de6f9d71f5ac): reencode to utf-8 before arrange rebase's todo list
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Doan Tran Cong Danh</sup>
>
> On [`musl libc`](https://www.musl-libc.org/), ISO-2022-JP encoder is too eager to switch back to 1 byte encoding, `musl`'s `iconv` always switch back after every combining character.
>   Comparing `glibc` and `musl`'s output for this command
>
> ```
> $ sed q t/t3900/ISO-2022-JP.txt| iconv -f ISO-2022-JP -t utf-8 `|`
>         iconv -f utf-8 -t ISO-2022-JP | xxd
>
> glibc: 
> 00000000: 1b24 4224 4f24 6c24 5224 5b24 551b 2842  .$B$O$l$R$[$U.(B
> 00000010: 0a                                       .
>
> musl: 
> 00000000: 1b24 4224 4f1b 2842 1b24 4224 6c1b 2842  .$B$O.(B.$B$l.(B
> 00000010: 1b24 4224 521b 2842 1b24 4224 5b1b 2842  .$B$R.(B.$B$[.(B
> 00000020: 1b24 4224 551b 2842 0a                   .$B$U.(B.
> ```
>
> Although `musl iconv`'s output isn't optimal, it's still correct.
>
> From [commit 7d509878b8](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7d509878b845a2a895cc880b833a016a06199981) ("[`pretty.c`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/0798d16fe38e45453b626c699d92de6f9d71f5ac/pretty.c): format string with truncate respects `logOutputEncoding`", 2014-05-21, Git v2.1.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/09e13ad5b0f0689418a723289dca7b3c72d538c4) listed in [batch #3](https://github.com/git/git/commit/cb682f8cfe63ecd0da08a526f404d295e51e3ab1)), we're encoding the message to utf-8 first, then format it and convert the message to the actual output encoding on [`git commit --squash`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit#Documentation/git-commit.txt---squashltcommitgt).
>
> Thus, `t3900::test_commit_autosquash_flags` is failing on `musl libc`.
>
> Reencode to utf-8 before arranging rebase's todo list.

---

> ### [`configure.ac`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1ba6e7aecdd2c72df1b0da7a89502e82485f7819): define `ICONV_OMITS_BOM` if necessary
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Doan Tran Cong Danh</sup>
>
> From [commit 79444c9294](https://github.com/git/git/commit/79444c92943048f9ac62e9311038ebe43f5f0982) ("`utf8`: handle systems that don't write BOM for UTF-16", 2019-02-12, Git v2.21.0-rc1 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/18f9fb687f708b568301a4af87194fd72e4010e0) listed in [batch #0](https://github.com/git/git/commit/)), we're supporting those systems with `iconv` that omits BOM with:
>
> ```
> make ICONV_OMITS_BOM=Yes
> ```
>
> However, configure script wasn't taught to detect those systems.
>
> Teach configure to do so.